# Android Pop on Custom View Clearing some portion of my drew line

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-custom-view

I am plotting a line on Custom view. But when I am poping Up any layout on the custom view , it is clearing some  random portion of drew line.

```
       @Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
{
super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.drawLine(0 , 200,700, 200, paint );
}
```

This is my Popup layout code.

```
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  
       popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.unavailablepopup, null);  
       DoneBtn    =  (Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.OkBtn);
       popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);      
       popupWindow.showAsDropDown(popupView, 250,250);
       bsweepOpen  = true;
```

*I have a doubt on onDraw(). I  have used Bitmap , but it didn't help. Any thing else I am missing in line plotting.* I am using a 40 miliseconds timer to invalidate() it.

Note: I don't want to reDraw(), so please don't waste time on that.

Comment: Where is the line drawn? In your custom Layout? You need to clarify where you are drawing.

Comment: No I mean I don't want solution to reDraw() if line is getting cleared.

Comment: So what do you want a 'solution' to exactly? I'm afraid your question is not clear.